# How to filter values out of a pivot table according to user input

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I am currently trying to change my pandas pivot table builder code to include a filter.

Users will be asked the following questions which will be used to filter values out:

```
filterindex = raw_input('Column to filter: ')
confilter = raw_input('Filter by <, > or != ?: ')
value = raw_input('Value to filter by: ')
```

Where the column "filterindex" will be filtered to exclude any values less than, more than or not equal to "value".

This is an example of how I'm trying to implement this filter on a pivot table already built according to earlier inputs:

```
 if confilter != "All Values" or confilter != "all values":
    if confilter == "<":
        table = table[table.filterindex < value]
```

My console, however, is returning the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'filterindex'
```

How do I rectify this so that the table is filtered according to the three questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here attribute access does not work, need general `[]`:

```
table = table[table[filterindex] < value]
```